Carga de datos de una tabla
Estoy haciendo un CRUD y no puedo hacer modeificaciones o eliminaciones desde una tabla html ya que no carga el 'id', por ende no carga los datos al momento de hacer la modificación o la baja del registro.
Este es el código de la tabla donde se muestran los registros.
<?php 

   //$sql="SELECT * FROM bandas_solistas INNER JOIN generos ON generos.id = bandas_solistas.id  ORDER BY nombre_banda";
   $sql="SELECT bandas_solistas.nombre_Banda, generos.genero, bandas_solistas.desde 
            FROM bandas_solistas 
            INNER JOIN generos ON generos.id = bandas_solistas.genero 
            ORDER BY bandas_solistas.nombre_Banda";
   $result=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
?>

<section>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Género</th>
                <th>Desde</th>
                <th>Modificar</th>
                <th>Eliminar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
            <?php while($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                <tr>                
                    <a><td><?php echo $registro['nombre_Banda']; ?></td></a>
                    <a><td><?php echo $registro['genero']; ?></td></a>
                    <a><td><?php echo $registro['desde']; ?></td></a>
                    <td><a href="modificar_bys.php?id=<?php echo $registro["id"] ?>"><img src="img\icon_modificar.jpg" height="10" alt="Modificar"> </a> </td>
                    <td><a href="eliminar_bys.php?id=<?php echo $registro["id"] ?>"><img src="img\icon_eliminar.jpg" height="10" alt="Eliminar"></a></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </section>
    
<!-- PIE DE PÁGINA -->
<footer>
<?php
        include('footer.php')
    ?>
</footer>

Este código es para cargar los datos del reguistro y que sean modificados:
    <!-- BODY -->

<?php 
$id=$_REQUEST["id"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bandas_solistas WHERE id='$id'";
$result = $conexion->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>

<form action="modificar_bys.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="modificar-bys">

    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">

    <label for="nombre_Banda">Nombre Banda/Solista:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nombre_Banda" name="nombre_Banda" value="<?php echo $row['nombre_Banda']?>" required><br><br>

    <label for="genero">Género:</label>
            <select type="text" name="genero" id="genero" size="4" required>             
              <?php
                $generos = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM generos");
                foreach ($generos as $opciones):
              ?>   
                <option value="<?php echo $opciones['id'] ?>"><?php echo $opciones['genero'] ?></option>                                      
              <?php endforeach ?>
            </select><br><br>
   
    <label for="desde">Desde:</label>
    <input type="text" id="desde" name="desde" value="<?php echo $row['desde']?>" required><br><br>

    
    <input type="submit" name="Modificar" value="Modificar Banda/Solista">
</form>

Y finalmente este el código para eliminar el registro
 <!-- BODY -->

<?php 
$id=$_REQUEST["id"];
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM bandas_solistas WHERE id='$id'";
$result2=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2);
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);

?>

<form action="eliminar_bys.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="eliminar-bys">

    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>">

    <label for="nombre_Banda">Nombre Banda/Solista:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nombre_Banda" name="nombre_Banda" value="<?php echo $row2['nombre_Banda']?>" required><br><br>


    <input type="submit" name="Eliminar" value="Eliminar Banda/Solista">
</form>

Estoy seguro que el problema está en la tabla consultas, ya que allí no se está cargando el id del registro que estoy queriendo modificar o eliminar.
Gracias.

En el SELECT no estás trayendo la columna id

Como apunta @Marcos en el 1er código no estás seleccionado el id, por tanto, la URL que construyes para el UPDATE o el DELETE no tendrá ese dato, esencial para ejecutar la acción. Por otra parte, no tiene sentido en tus dos últimos códigos volver a seleccionar los datos. Para actualizar sólo necesitas un UPDATE laTabla SET laColumna=elValor WHERE laColumnaID=elValorDelId y para borrar un DELETE FROM laTabla WHERE laColumnaID=elValorDelId. En ambos casos elValorDelId será pasado en la URL. En cuanto al UPDATE debes indicar de algún modo qué columnas se modifican y sus valores.

Debo agregar que este tipo de cosas son más simples de realizar mediante Ajax. Por ejemplo, para el caso del UPDATE puedes escuchar por Javascript los input del formulario que cambian e ir metiendo los nuevos valores dentro de un objeto, el cual mandarás al servidor para la actualización, siempre junto con el ID. Supongamos que cambia sólo el nombre, la escucha te construirá un objeto como este: {id:9, nombre:'Nuevo Nombre'} Lo que te permitirá en el servidor escribir esta consulta: UPDATE laTabla SET nombre='Nuevo Nombre'  WHERE elID=9. Y todo limpiamente, sin recargar página.

Muchas gracias, lo pude resolver, efectivamente era el ID.

Además podría añadir que cuando intentas obtener la id del formulario usas $_REQUEST:
$id=$_REQUEST["id"];
y podrías intentar obtenerlo desde el propio POST del formulario:
$id=$_POST["id"];
Así aprovechas el propio method del form para obtener los valores que necesitas de él.
